# Exchange Active Sync Connection Issue

Tags: exchange, imap, iphone, activesync

I configured my exchange 2016 server to accept imap SSL 993 connections, however when i try to configure account A (test account with user right only) it received email with no issue, but when i setup my administrator email account it can't receive or send email?

Thanks.

Comment: This is by design. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-mailbox-access?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

Have you received some NDR? Error messages?

I want to confirm that the administrator mailbox can send and receive emails through outlook or OWA?

Compare administrator with test user in configuration, In addition to administrative privileges.

In addition, I recommend to configure a new ActiveSync device with problematic account.

If it works fine, it indicates that profile setting on current ActiveSync device is corrupt, we need to remove the account profile and reboot mobile device, then re-configure it again for testing.

If it remains existing in new device, please try to restart IIS or recycle MSExchangeSyncAppPool on Exchange server.